# Using <?php echo get_num_queries(); ?> queries in and i see 7000+queries?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have put  queries in  seconds. in my footer.php and i see more than

> 7000 queries in about 9 secs

, is this a lot??

On my localhost

> i have 195 queries in 3,070 seconds.

As the live version is slow i like to know if the queries could be the cause? And what would be the best step by step way to monitor/reduce the queries?

How can i check which code triggers the queries?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

195 queries for one page is a lot. 7000 queries is not a lot, it is insane.

Install [Query Monitor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/). It tracks all queries and presents them in groups.

[image]

I don’t know if it *can* track that many queries, this is probably an interesting stress test. :)

Find the source of those queries, deactivate it. If you are not sure what the source is, disable all plugins and switch to the default theme. Does it still happen? If it doesn’t reactivate each component separately until the queries explode again.